# Davrods (irods client) installation on centos

Tags: webdav

I am trying to install davrods but I think the web site is missing some steps.

I am following the steps on https://github.com/UtrechtUniversity/davrodshttps://github.com/UtrechtUniversity/davrods . I already have my irods server running and I can use icommands.The prerequisites i did were these listed below and after I could install the davrods on my centos 7. I also configured as say in your git repository.

On the file "/etc/httpd/conf.d/davrods-vhost.conf" I uncomment the lines were necessary and changed some configurations:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName 145.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
    <Location />
       DirectoryIndex disabled
        AuthType Basic
        Require valid-user
        AuthName DAV
        Dav davrods-locallock
        DavRodsEnvFile  /etc/httpd/irods/irods_environment.json
        DavRodsServer 145.xxx.xxx.xxx 1247
        DavRodsZone tempZone
        DavRodsAuthScheme PAM
        DavRodsDefaultResource demoResc
        DavRodsExposedRoot  Home
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

My httpd version is correct "Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)"

I mean, if you are using apache httpd. Where is the war file that I can copy to

```
yum install boost jansson
wget ftp://ftp.renci.org/pub/irods/releases/4.1.9/centos7/irods-runtime-4.1.9-centos7-x86_64.rpm
rpm -i irods-runtime-4.1.9-centos7-x86_64.rpm
rpm -i davrods-1.1.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
#######################################################################
##                                                                     
##         + Davrods post-install note for SELinux users +             
##                                                                     
## If your SELinux is set to Enforcing, you may need to make changes   
## to your policies to allow davrods to run:                           
##                                                                     
## - Apache HTTPD must be allowed to connect to TCP port 1247          
## - iRODS plugin libs in /var/lib/irods/plugins/network               
##   must have 'lib_t' SELinux context.                                
##                                                                     
## For example, the following two commands can be used to resolve these
## requirements:
##
## setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect true
## chcon -t lib_t /var/lib/irods/plugins/network/lib*.so

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect true
chcon -t lib_t /var/lib/irods/plugins/network/lib*.so
```

Kind Regards
Felipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got how to use PAM+SSL on iRODS through this tutorial http://slides.com/irods/ugm2016-ssl-and-pam#/ . Now I am struggling with Davrods because it does not recognize the user I typed on the https connection. I type user "felipe" and the http.log says I am using rods user.

```
[Wed Oct 05 09:20:04.114976 2016] [davrods:warn] [pid 7623] [client 145.117.144.114:50740] rcPamAuthRequest failed: -993000 = PAM_AUTH_PASSWORD_FAILED
[Wed Oct 05 09:20:04.123410 2016] [auth_basic:error] [pid 7623] [client 145.117.144.114:50740] AH01617: user rods: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch
```

Answer (score 0):

I've already responded to this question by mail, but I'll add it over here
for completeness (modified slightly since you changed your question a bit):

> I mean, if you are using apache httpd. Where is the war file that I
>   can copy

The [Davrods RPM](https://github.com/UtrechtUniversity/davrods/releases) that
you have installed places the necessary files in the right directories for
you[1], so there's no WAR file to install. (Besides, with Davrods being a C library instead of Java, it doesn't come in a WAR format).

After setting up the vhost config, restarting httpd should be all that's
left to do to get davrods up and running.

Now, for the vhost you'll want to choose either port 80 without SSL settings, or port 443 with SSL settings. Since you're using PAM, I assume you like to use SSL for your WebDAV connection.

To use SSL, change `*:80` to `*:443` in the head of the vhost config, and add your SSL settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName 145.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /path/to/davrods.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/davrods.key
    ...
```

When you've restarted httpd, try connecting using your WebDAV client or a web browser.
If you get an error message, detailed information can be found in your
httpd error log (`/var/log/httpd/error_log`) or
otherwise `/var/log/messages`.

> I think [the web site](https://github.com/UtrechtUniversity/davrods) is missing some steps

Thanks for the feedback, I'll see if I can make the last part of the setup more clear!

[1] You can see the installed files with `rpm -qlp DAVRODS_RPM_FILE`.
`/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_davrods.so` is the actual Davrods program.